# How to specify mongo database when locally connecting

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a local database called `test` with a collection called `posts`.

The following works fine

```py
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
db = client.test
collection = db.list_collection_names()
```

However, when I try to specify the database within the mongo uri, I get an error

```py
test_db = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
collection = test_db.list_collection_names()

TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'list_collection_names' method on a 'MongoClient' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

How can I specify the database directly in the uri?

Answer (score 0):

With `mongodb://localhost:27017/test` you're still just connecting to the mongodb instance but specifying a default database in the connection. You're not directly connecting to the `test` database.

```py
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
dbs = client.list_database_names()
print(dbs) #['admin', 'config', 'local', 'test']
```

To access the default database in the uri do

```py
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
db = client.get_database()
collection = db.list_collection_names()
```